# C# Create an object and add to a list

Tags: c#, list, oop

I have a basic csharp objects question. I want to add my emails to a list and display their content.

I have created my object class:

```
 public class Email{
        public string EmailSubject {get; set;} 
        public string EmailContent {get; set;}
        public Email(String Subject, String Content)
        {
            EmailSubject = Subject;
            EmailContent = Content;
        }
```

Then I want to create a list and start making object to add to them and display.

```
    List<Email> Emails = new List<Email>();
    Emails.Add(new Email() {EmailSubject="MySubject", EmailContent="MyContent"} );

    Console.WriteLine();
    foreach (Email e in Emails)
    {
     Console.WriteLine(e);
    }
```

However, I am getting this error:

```
There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'Subject' of 'Email.Email(string, string)'
```

I have also attempted to do this

```
Emails.Add(new Email(EmailSubject="MySubject", EmailContent="MyContent" ));
```

but my out is simply `Email`

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: This is basic constructor syntax. The first way fails because you do not have a constructor that takes no parameters and the second fails because you are not using the correct syntax (`Emails.Add(new Email("MySubject", "MyContent" )`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are trying to call parameterless constructor in new new Email() and its not specified

you can just add

```
public Email(){}
```

or use existing

```
new Email("Subject","Content")
```

For printing then you need to override and call method e.ToString()

add method to Email class

```
public override string ToString()
{
     return $"Subject-{EmailSubject} Content-{EmailContent};
}
```

then in `foreach`

```
Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

Your only constructor has 2 parameters hence the error referring to `Email.Email(string, string)` as you attempting to instantiate `Email` with zero parameters.

You should either remove the constructor from your code and use property intialisers as you already do. This works as the compiler will create a default constructor in the absence of any others.

```
new Email() {
    EmailSubject="MySubject",
    EmailContent="MyContent"
}
```

or leave the constructor and create an instance like this.

```
new Email("MySubject", "MyContent"}
```

Pick one, it makes little difference.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove that constructor with two arguments and do this object initialization.

```
List<Email> Emails = new List<Email>();
Emails.Add(new Emails{ EmailSubject = "Something", EmailContent = "Also Something"});
```